# Directory Listing Denied : This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed

Tags: hosting, modx, modx-evolution, windows-hosting

I am hosting a modx website on ixwebhosting.com

After I submitted the site, I get this message when I try and access the root for example:

```
wwww.website.com/
```

or

```
www.website.com/manager/
```

I can get it to work, however, if I go directly to :

```
www.website.com/index.php
```

or

```
www.website.com/manager/index.php
```

ixwebhosting.com offers **windows hosting**

What do you think is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the virtual directory (gear icon) in IIS snapin, click Properties.

Check the box that says 'Directory browsing'

Click okay (and possibly?) restart IIS.

Comment: Also, under document tab check the box 'Enable default content page' and make sure index.php is in the list.

Comment: Are you referring to ixwebhosting.com's CMS?

Comment: After upload, WordPress root folder and db, my website show my root folder files in the browser, may i know what is my error?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the default document setting is not "turned on" for the IIS